# Are constant functions linear?

Tags: math, geometry, computer-science, coordinate-transformation, computer-science-theory

Linear functions in mathematics are those polynomials whose degree is 1 and hence they are straight in nature when plotted on a graph. But the constant functions like f(x) = 3, even though their degree is 0, are straight in nature when plotted on a graph. Can’t we call them linear?

Comment: This is probably more suitable for http://www.math.stackexchange.com. I'm not sure if there is a universally agreed-upon convention for whether the term "linear function" also includes constant functions. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_function) defines a "linear function" as a polynomial of either degree 1 or degree 0. Hopefully it will be clear from the context whenever you come across the term.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Comment: Please, check this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2495825/is-constant-function-also-a-linear-function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say they are not. There is some confusion between the equation of a straight line and the concept of linearity.

A *linear* function is additive, i.e. `f(x+y) = f(x)+f(y)`, which is not true for a constant function.

The equation of a straight line through the origin `y = m.x` is indeed linear, but the equation of a general line `y = m.x + p` is not.

A linear function with an additional constant is called *affine*. Hence a constant function is affine.

Answer (score 1):

There are both opinions, however claim of Yves Daoust is simply wrong. Consider

```
<i>f(x) = 2x +5 </br>
f(2) = 9</br>
f(3) = 11</br>
f(5) = 15</i>
```

which is definitely not 20...

Comment: You perfectly misunderstood my answer. I call 2x+5 affine, not linear. An affine function does not fulfill the linearity conditions.